# Can't ping first IP with dual NICs on different subnets with multiple gateways

Tags: networking, rhel

I have two NICs assigned to a server.

```
eth0 - 10.199.10.0/24 w/ a GW of 10.199.10.1
eth1 - 10.199.20.0/24 w/ a GW of 10.199.20.1
```

From my desktop, I can ping the IP assigned to each NIC just fine (`10.199.10.100` and `10.199.20.100`). So I set up Apache to listen on ALL ips on said server. I tested this just fine from my desktop as well. Now, I went to create a new VM on the `10.199.20.0` subnet and I can access the RH test page by hitting `http://10.199.20.100` BUT I can't access it via `10.199.10.100`.

This is troublesome since I have a bunch of services on this server that can only listen on one particular IP (the `10.199.10.100`). My network guy tells me the routes look fine and that it could be the routing table on the server itself.

```
#ip route
10.199.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link src 10.199.10.100
10.199.20.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link src 10.199.20.100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003
default via 10.199.10.1 dev eth0

# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all to 10.199.20.100 lookup build
32765:  from 10.199.20.100 lookup build
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

***Netowrk Layout***

These servers are Xen guests. We have four Xen servers with multiple NICs. The admin server with the two NICs have two virtual NICs assigned to them. One from `10.199.10.x` and one from the `10.199.20.x` subnet (two different NICs). The test server only has the `10.199.20.x` network assigned to it. I can ping the `10.199.30.x` network just fine.

Comment: What does `netstat -tln|grep -w 80` show?

Comment: VM? What VM - please explain that bit (especially the network setup of your VM in relation to your server).

Comment: see edits above. netstat shows `0.0.0.0:80` I can hit both IPs via Apache from my desktop just fine.

Comment: (1) Does your desktop has IP(s) for both subnet? (2) Where is the VM residing? (in your desktop machine?) (3) Please post following: From desktop and from VM (3a) `traceroute 10.199.10.100` (3b) `traceroute 10.199.20.100`. Potential solution: (4a) Add one more interface to your VM, assign a 10.199.20.x IP to it, (4b) Add 10.199.20.x IP to existing VM nic. If that works I will move this to answer.